# TensorFlow with Anaconda on macbook, "open with Jupyter/IPython Notebook" options disabled

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter

I installed TensorFlow and Anaconda on my macbook pro and it seems to work fine, I can import tensorflow and execute commands on the command line, however I would like to use tensorflow in IPython notebooks. When I go to Anaconda Navigator -> environments - > TensorFlow, you can click the little arrow to "open terminal", "open with python" (both work fine) OR "open with IPython", "open with Jupyter Notebook". The last two options are disabled for some reason which I can't figure out. How do I enable them?

Comment: Did you install  `jupyter` into your TensorFlow environment?

Comment: No. I thought it'd be there since I do see a Jupyter Notebook icon on the Home button in Anaconda Navigator and it works fine, but I don't see it in the list of installed packages under tensorflow environment. I'm confused..

Comment: You need to install all the packages you want to use into each environment where you want to use them. Conda tries to make each environment as independent as possible. Simply writing `conda install -n tensorflow notebook ipython` should work.

Comment: Ok, I installed Jupyter under the tensorflow environment by launching a terminal (from tensorflow environment arrow in Navigator) and executing the command: {conda install --name tensorflow jupyter}. Now I can see the two notebook options enabled and I can launch a Jupyter notebook fine, however I can't import tensorflow into it. Getting an {ImportError: No module named tensorflow}. The IPython shell (option 3) imports tensorflow just fine and I can create a session and execute TF commands just fine. Not sure what's going on with Jupyter notebook.

Comment: What's the output of printing `sys.path`?

Comment: /Users/kai/anaconda/lib/python2.7 ..etc. It's not pointing to the tensorflow environment!! I expected it to be since I launch the Jupyter notebook from the tensorflow environment in Navigator.. the path should be (i think) : /Users/kai/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7..

Comment: here's the full output of sys.path: ['',
 '/Users/kai/anaconda/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/kai/anaconda/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/kai/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/kai/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/kai/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/kai/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/kai/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/kai/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/kai/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/kai/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.3-py2.7.egg',
....]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so installing Jupyter with the tensorflow environment was required to activate the two ipython/Jupyter Notebook selection in Anaconda Navigator (as advised by @darthbith ). As for the import error, I found a workaround, NOT a solution, which is to activate the tensorflow environment in a terminal, then launching a Jupyter notebook from that terminal. Then I was able to import and use tensorflow in my Jupyter notebook. In addition, all imports are now looking at the tensorflow environment not the "root" environment. I'm Happy!!

Comment: That is the solution, not a workaround. You have to activate the environment before you can use it. I'm not sure what the Anaconda launcher is or isn't doing that it isn't activating the right environment before launching the process. See if there's an `activate` option somewhere in the Anaconda launcher.

Comment: I was expecting that when you select tensorflow in the Environments tab (in anaconda navigator) that this would activate tensorflow env. But maybe the GUI designers did not intend that to be the case.